# Inference on the significance of an exogenous variable

Tags: regression, statistical-significance

I fitted a regression equation with a set of `n` exogenous variables, and estimate of regression coefficient with one of these variables obtained as $\beta = 0.00001$ with $SE = 0.000005$. Therefore the `z-value` comes as `0.00001/0.000005` which is `2`.

My question is if we should consider this variable as significant? Yes, from statistical information pov it is significant given it's `z-value`. But from the practical pov, given that the estimate itself is very small i.e. $\beta = 0.00001$, should this variable be considered as significant?

Comment: The answer depends on context and background information that you do not provide. Search for posts about the difference between statistically significant and practically significant.